# How do I respond to people who downvote my question if their answer was not correct?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes

There was an answer here: [How do I uninstall apps that I can't find?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/246062/how-do-i-uninstall-apps-that-i-cant-find/246101#246101)

It didn't answer the question, so I downvoted it and commented. The author then deleted his answer and downvoted my question.

This is why people don't downvote as per: [People Never Down-Vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26224/people-never-down-vote)

Generally downvotes are to be complemented with a comment explanation, as they should be. This reveals identity and then usually causes people to downvote you back. This is why I rarely downvote.

This question isn't about explaining downvotes but to prevent revenge and retaliation downvote.

Comment: How can you be sure that the answerer downvoted your question?

Comment: There's no rule about downvoting and commenting. It's **nice** if you comment but it's not **required**.

Comment: @Glorfindel There are 24 views on the question. The question is 14 hours old. I downvoted and commented, then within the 15 seconds after, the answer was deleted and my question went to -1. We don't need a mathematician to find out that the probability the down-voter was more than likely also the answerer. :)

Comment: `Generally down-votes are to be complimented with a comment explanation, as they should be.`  *That* is your false premise, rather than that you shouldn't downvote.  Be much more careful about when you comment, and try to do so only when you're reasonably confident that the post author is someone who's actually open to constructive criticism.

Comment: @Catija In my experiences, in most cases it's not even nice.  As much as people complain about downvotes without comments, they get much more upset when people actually explain why they're wrong.

Comment: @Servy I mean that the comment is a way of explaining how the post can be improved... and thus, is nice... how someone reacts to that comment doesn't make it less nice.

Comment: @Catija You and I both think learning about problems with a post is nice.  In my experiences, the vast majority of people disagree, and feel that pointing out problems with a post, regardless of the manor of doing so, tends to be taken as an attack.

Comment: @Servy Considering the number of people I see complaining "why you no explain dv", I don't think I can agree with that.

Comment: @Catija Like I said, people love to complain about downvotes without a comment.  They also tend to like comments explaining why their posts are wrong *much* less.  People complain about not getting comments until they actually get comments, then they complain even more about those comments.  The number of people that thank someone for pointing out a problem in their answer is *very* small.

Answer (score 20):

Couple of things here.

1. You did well to explain why you downvoted the answer, and you should not stop doing it.
2. You should not respond to the downvote you got, even if you think it's from that answer's author.

I'll elaborate on the second part a bit. First and foremost, responding to such a thing will never end well. It will just lead to a fight, where both sides lose. Second, you can't know for sure that was that user. Maybe it was, maybe not.

Better leave it alone, absorb the -2 reputation, and keep posting good contents.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you did the right thing.  I compliment you on explaining what the problem with the answer is.

Downvoting and commenting is slightly "riskier" than just downvoting: there's a higher likelihood of drama, negative reactions, or revenge downvoting.  In an ideal world, everyone would respond professionally and maturely to criticism, but we're not in an ideal world, so you have to be prepared that some small fraction of users might not react well to criticism.

For that reason, I know that some people try to avoid leaving a comment when they downvote.  What you want to do is up to you.  If you find it extremely bothersome to occasionally encounter hostile reactions when you comment and downvote, you might consider just downvoting without leaving a comment (or if you prefer, leaving a comment without downvoting).

There is absolutely no requirement to leave a comment when you downvote.  Don't let anyone pressure you into commenting whenever you downvote.

Ideally, everyone would respond maturely to criticism, and everyone would leave constructive feedback on answers that are wrong -- but in practice that won't always be the case, so be prepared, and act accordingly.  Personally, I try to act according to how I'd want to see everyone act in an ideal world, and ignore revenge downvoting and other negative reactions, in the spirit of "be the change you want to see in the world"... but you can choose your own path.